# User typing text onto a Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Is there a way to put user typed text over a canvas and keeps on expanding as the user types?
I'm trying to create a website that allows the user to input various comments in the form of bullet notes as a way to "comment" on a certain image/picture.

In short, I'm trying to recreate what power-point does with it's bullet system as you can see here: http://i60.tinypic.com/k4z8f7.png

Making a textbox's position absolute works, but it's very ugly and isn't really what I want.
I'm fine with a solution that doesn't use a canvas as well.

Comment: Why can't you use a textbox? You didn't explain that well.

Comment: I'm still new to javascript, but I don't think it's possible to make it so that the textbox expands as the user types beyond 1 line and the next bullet would come on the next line once the user presses enter. If there is a way, please let me know.

Comment: See: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZSwr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `contenteditable`. Contenteditable elements can be edited using a native rich-text editor by the browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZSwr/

Code to use contenteditable (just add the `contenteditable` attribute):

```
<div contenteditable>
    <ul>
        <li>This is the stackoverflow logo</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```